# when norm of an operator is given by max of eigen values modulas

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis, normed-spaces

Could any one tell me how this $\|x\|^2=\|x*x\|$ and the rest of it?[image: here]

I know $\|x\|=\|x^*\|$, I also understand $x^*x$  is hermitian and so diagonalizale but then did not understand the norm square equal to max of eigen valuess etc thank you  for helping

Answer (score 1):

From your first expression
$$\|x\|^{2}=\sup_{\|\xi\|=1}\overline{\xi}^{t}x^{\star}x\xi.$$
If $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue of $x^{\star}x$ then $\lambda$ is real and non-negative, and there exist a unit eigenvector $\xi$ of $x^{\star}x$ with eigenvalue $\lambda$, from which it follows that $\|x\|^{2} \ge \overline{\xi}^{t}x^{\star}x\xi=\lambda\|\xi\|^{2}=\lambda$. If $\lambda_{0} > \lambda_{1} > \cdots > \lambda_{k} \ge 0$ are the distinct eigenvalues of $x^{\star}x$, then, because $x^{\star}x$ is Hermitian, every unit vector $\xi$ can be written as an orthogonal sum
$$
               \xi = \xi_{0}+\xi_{1}+\cdots +\xi_{k},\;\;\; \overline{\xi_{j}}^{t}\xi_{k}=0 \mbox{ for }  j\ne k,
$$
where
$$
       x^{\star}x\xi_{k}=\lambda_{k}\xi_{k},\;\;\;1=\|\xi_{0}\|^{2}+\|\xi_{1}\|^{2}+\cdots+\|x_{i}\|^{2}.
$$
(We allow any $\xi_{k}$ to be $0$ in order to have a general such representation.) Then
$$
\begin{align}
           \overline{\xi^{t}}x^{\star}x\xi & = \lambda_{0}\|\xi_{0}\|^{2}+\lambda_{1}\|\xi_{1}\|^{2}+\cdots+\lambda_{k}\|\xi_{k}\|^{2} \\
      & \le \lambda_{0}(\xi_{0}\|^{2}+\|\xi_{1}\|^{2}+\cdots+\|\xi_{k}\|^{2}) = \lambda_{0}.
\end{align}
$$
Therefore, $\|x\|^{2} \le \lambda_{0}$ also holds. Thus, $\|x\|^{2}$ is the maximum eigenvalue of $x^{\star}x$.